# Cannot add APT repository

Tags: command-line, apt, repository

Hi I tried adding a repository via `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:diesch/testing` in Ubuntu 18.04.

After a long wait, the output is some information about the repo and then the prompt

`Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it`

However, pressing Enter just starts a new line in the terminal (just to be clear it just adds a line-break, it does not result in a fresh line starting with `$`).

The repository is not added successfully.

What causes this behavior? And what am I missing in here?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Thanks. That PPA should be valid for 18.04 so that's one potential problem that can be discounted.

Comment: @Pentaquark , which package are you trying to install? and how you checked if added? have you check `/etc/apt/sources.d/`